# PostgreSQL db externa en Django

Tags: postgresql

Tengo un proyecto Django y uso una base de datos postgresql en local y va perfecta con el modulo psycopg2, ahora bien, le pongo una base de datos externa y cuando hago un migrate da el siguiente error.

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "local-IP", user "postgres", database "chewbacca_db", SSL on
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "local-IP", user "postgres", database "my_db", SSL off
```

y en mi proyecto django lo tengo asi... como siempre

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'my_db',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'external-server-IP',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}
```

No entiendo porque me sale la dirección IP del servidor local en el error... si en settings.py no hay esa IP en ningún lado.

**SOLUCIÓN:**

Se ha editado el fichero **postgresql.conf** cambiando `listenaddresses='localhost'` por `listenaddresses='*'` y en el fichero **pg_hba.conf** se ha añadido en el apartado de IPv4 `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5` acto seguido se hace un restart del servicio **sudo service postgresql restart** y voliá.

Comment: Ingresa al shell de Django y fíjate qué aparece en las variables de tu base de datos con `settings.DATABASES`, tal vez se estén usando múltiples archivos de configuración o el clásico `local_settings`.

Comment: La IP del servidor la tendrás seguramente en el `pg_hba.conf`. Añade este fichero a la pregunta ([+info sobre pg_hba.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html))

Comment: ¿Tienes permisos en la base de datos externa? ¿Tu base de datos externa acepta conexiones foráneas? No parece un error de Django sino de configuración de Postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay que revisar varias cosas:

1. Que el servidor donde se aloja la base de datos no tenga un firewall activo o que si lo tiene esté abierto el puerto 5432 (o el que sea que esté configurado, el 5432 es el puerto por defecto).
2. Que en el archivo pg_hba.conf figure una entrada para el IP donde está el programa en python. Ahí hay muchas posibilidades (se puede habilitar para un uno o más usuarios o all, para una o más bases de datos o all, para cierto IP o rangos de IP. Atención que después de modificar pg_hba.conf hay que reiniciar el postgresql